# How to detect if a checkbox has been clicked with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many checkboxes that I would like to add the values of to an array in a session variable. problem is I don't know what the ID of checkbox will be. the checkboxes will look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="102" name="tags[]" id="tag102" class="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" value="103" name="tags[]" id="tag103" class="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" value="104" name="tags[]" id="tag104" class="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" value="105" name="tags[]" id="tag105" class="checkbox" />
```

The first step is that I'm trying to detect if they have been clicked with this little bit, but I'm not getting anything, no errors and no entry in the console.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
    console.log("box was clicked");
    alert("box clicked...");
});
```

What am I doing wrong.

The script is loaded in a document ready function.
the latest jquery & bootstrap3 are loaded before this.

**UPDATE**

Looks like something is interfering with the checkbox:

```
// type ahead search
    var allclients_ajaxUrl = '[[~41]]';

    $('#searchusers').select2({  
      minimumInputLength: 2,
      ajax: {
        url: allclients_ajaxUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function (term, page) {
          return {
            q2: term
          };
        },
        results: function (data, page) {
          return { results: data };
        }
      }
    });
```

Not sure how or why that would be messing up the select boxes.

Comment: Is the script wrapped in a DOM ready function or at the end of the HTML?

Comment: That's weird, seeing that both (click / change) are triggered: http://jsfiddle.net/LtR3S/. What version of jquery are you using?

Comment: you probably need to wrap it in document.ready function

Answer (score 2):

I think you're not wrapping your jQuery code inside the document ready function. Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
      console.log($(this).attr('id') + "box was clicked");
      alert($(this).attr('id') + " box clicked...");
   });
});
```

Using the `this` keyword would provide you with only the element that is triggering the event. So you won't have to worry about the array of the checkboxes inside the document.

Secondly, you can trigger the click event on the checkbox too. If you want to detect the click function. `.click()`.

#### ...or

You're not linking the jQuery to your document at all.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

This would include the jQuery for your document.

Comment: Yes, I have it in a doc ready function & after [the latest] jquery is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Seems fine here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
        console.log("box was clicked "+$(this).attr('id'));    
    });    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Gz3Zb/

Comment: Sorry - your does work, I missed that it was logging to the console...  but see the updated post. something else is interfering with the select boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aRFWN/)**

```
$('input[type=checkbox] ').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    alert("checked for : " + this.id);
  }
});
```

This return the `id` for checkbox which is checked.

Comment: I copied and pasted exactly what youhave there [in doc ready] & I see your fiddle works, mine does not! no errors or anything in the console.

Comment: Did you included JS librery?

Comment: yes - see the update to the post. something else is interfering with the checkboxes somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Use the checked selector http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

E.g.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        // do something when checked
    } else {
        // do something when unchecked
    }
});
```

Personally I use click events for checkboxes. They seem to work better than change.

Further you can access the id or value property of the checkbox that's currently clicked/changed, using this.value and this.id (inside the function "this" refers to the DOM element).

Answer (score 0):

$("input:checked") will return all the checkboxes and radio boxes that are currently checked.  You could iterate over that and just add the values to the array.

Comment: True but you'd have to interate over the checkboxes every time the value in one of them changes. Unfortunately that puts us right back with the same question of how to attach the `.change()` event handler...

Comment: The way I read the question, it seemed like he just needed to get the values.  I wasn't sure whether or not he would need a real-time update and someone had already posted that solution, so maybe this would help.